# Como abrir um Form( ou ocultar um Form) dentro de um Panel por um outro Form

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação em C# e gostaria de saber se teria como quando eu apertasse o botão de adicionar(cujo a seta esta apontando na imagem) esse form que esta em azul mais claro que esta dentro de um Panel se fechasse e abrisse um outro form que no caso seria o frmCadastro.

Estava usando esse codigo pra ver se abria, porem sem sucesso:

```
frmPaginaInicial pg = new frmPaginaInicial();
pg.painelMenu.Controls.Clear();

Leitor.frmAddLeitor ad = new Leitor.frmAddLeitor();
ad.TopLevel = false;
ad.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
ad.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

pg.painelMenu.Controls.Add(ad);
ad.Show();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá algum erro? Coloque mais detalhes na sua questão pf.

Comment: Uma dúvida, você disse na pergunta que gostaria de abrir o formulário `frmCadastro`, mas no seu código está criando o formulário `frmAddLeitor`. Afinal, qual formulário você gostaria de abrir?

Comment: Eu já consegui achar a solução, mas obrigado pela atenção João

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você precisa pegar sua instância atual (que está criada e salva em memória) da classe `frmPaginaInicial`, assim o resto do seu código irá funcionar normalmente:

```
// Aqui pegamos a instância atual da classe "frmPaginaInicial"
frmPaginaInicial pg = Application.OpenForms["frmPaginaInicial"] as frmPaginaInicial;
// Removemos todos os controles do painel menu
pg.painelMenu.Controls.Clear();

// Criamos uma nova instância do frmAddLeitor
Leitor.frmAddLeitor ad = new Leitor.frmAddLeitor();

// Dizemos que não é o elemento principal/elemento pai
ad.TopLevel = false;
// Preenchemos o painel por completo
ad.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
// Retiramos a borda
ad.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
// Adiciona o formulário dentro do painel menu
pg.painelMenu.Controls.Add(ad);
// Mostramos o formulário
ad.Show();
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado Pedro Paulo

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou e pode ajudar outras pessoas, marque-a como resposta aceita por favor. Obrigado! :)